# Prevent Vim from updating its undo tree

Tags: vim, undo

I have a Vimscript function which is called on `BufWritePre` to check the integrity of the file. Typically  this involves trimming whitespace and checking that the fold structure is "valid" (according to my company's conventions).

My problem is that if I edit a file and then save it, the undo tree contains the edits made by the checking function. Is there a simple way to say that I don't want a function to modify the undo tree? Or can I save its state at the start of the function and restore it at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `:undojoin`, you can join your changes with the last changes done by the user (though I would find that more confusing than having them separate). In general, undo is sequence of steps; you cannot simply omit steps in the middle, that would both be unintuitive and also difficult to implement in the undo engine.

Anyway, what's so bad about including your automatic reformatting in the undo history? As I understand it, it'll be re-applied on the next save when the user undoes his last edits.

Comment: Thanks, you make some good points. I need to rethink what I was trying to achieve. The `undojoin` command may come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

If your `BufWritePre` action is performing manipulations that ultimately leave your file unchanged, you can:

```
:wundo <tmpfile>
```

...Make changes leaving file the same afterwards...

```
:rundo <tmpfile>
```

This will leave you with your undo history prior to the temporary change, however if the file doesn't match it's previous state you'll get the error `File contents changed, cannot use undo info`.

If you wish to make the changes done during the `BufWritePre` impossible to undo, you can:

```
:set noundofile
```

.. Perform changes ...

```
:set undofile
```

However, this will lose all history prior to the `BufWritePre`

Comment: This looks great, thanks. Why will this only work if the file is unchanged? In general the file will change, but I don't want to be able to undo the changes.

Comment: @PrinceGoulash Do you want to be able to undo changes prior to the `BufWritePre` action?

Comment: Yes. So if I add a word and then save, `u` should remove the word, regardless of any whitespace changes that saving has triggered.

Comment: @PrinceGoulash As far as I can see, that's not possible, the undo file format is based on a sequence of diffs and therefore can't have missing information in it otherwise it wouldn't be able to reproduce the intervening state.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. However, your `wundo`/`rundo` solution seems to work in the simple cases I have just tried. Thanks for your helpful answer.